# How to Search and Remove Specific Anchor Tag from Specific Span Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list. How do I remove specific options according to their text values in the anchor tag and the text value from the group-lable class? Say I want to remove Option 1 from Group 1, how can that be done?
:

```html
<div class="non-selected-wrapper">
  <div class="header">All options</div>
  <div class="item-group">
    <span class="group-label">Group1</span>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11050" multi-index="0">Option1</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11052" multi-index="1">Option2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-group">
    <span class="group-label">Group2</span>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11064" multi-index="2">Option1</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11053" multi-index="3">Option2</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11054" multi-index="4">Option3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-group">
    <span class="group-label">Group3</span>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11051" multi-index="5">Option1</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11056" multi-index="6">Option2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vanilla Javascript:

```js
const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('.group-label')];
const groupToRemoveFrom = "Group1";
const optionToRemove = "Option1";

const target = [
  ...labels
    .filter(x => x.textContent === groupToRemoveFrom)[0]
    .parentNode.querySelectorAll('a')
  ].filter(x => x.textContent === optionToRemove)[0];

target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
```

```html
<div class="non-selected-wrapper">
  <div class="header">All options</div>
  <div class="item-group">
    <span class="group-label">Group1</span>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11050" multi-index="0">Option1</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11052" multi-index="1">Option2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-group">
    <span class="group-label">Group2</span>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11064" multi-index="2">Option1</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11053" multi-index="3">Option2</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11054" multi-index="4">Option3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-group">
    <span class="group-label">Group3</span>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11051" multi-index="5">Option1</a>
    <a tabindex="0" class="item" role="button" data-value="11056" multi-index="6">Option2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To specifically do what you are asking, you would use this code:

```
$("span.group-label:contains('Group1')").closest(".item-group").find("a.item:contains('Option1')").remove()
```

To make it more generic, you will need to understand these selectors.  Basically, I am finding a span with class 'group-label' which contains text "Group1".  From there, I am traversing up to its parent "item-group".  Within that, I am finding an anchor of class "item" which contains the text "Option1" and removing it.

You could of course add whatever logic you needed to this, if you don't specifically want to remove that one item.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel! That works beautifully!!